# php within php to include wordpress custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to incorporate an image slider shortcode into a custom WordPress theme template, so that the client will be able to paste the shortcode into the custom field and the template will read this and display it correctly. I do not want the client to paste the shortcode in the body of the post, as the slider needs to be displayed outside of the post wrapper (at full browser width).

I don't know much about php, so would really appreciate any help with this!

The code I have so far to display the slider via the template is:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[metaslider id=27]"); ?>
```

And to display the output of custom fields I have:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slider', true); ?>
```

Each of these works on its own, but I need to combine them, so that the client doesn't have to edit the template just to add the shortcode. So I am thinking something like this should work:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slider', true); ?>]"); ?>
```

... but it doesn't.

Many thanks in advance for any help with this.

C

Comment: You cant use do_shortcode like that. You can only use do_shortcode to reference an actual shortcode.

Comment: So what do you suggest in this instance? How do I get this to work?

Comment: I'm still staring at this and wondering myself. It's a good question :)

Comment: I think I just figured it out. This seems to work:

Comment: <?php echo do_shortcode(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slider', true)); ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply pass the return value of `get_post_meta` (which would contain the shortcode as far as I understood) to the `do_shortcode` function as an argument:

```
do_shortcode(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slider', true));
```

Comment: Figured it out then this answer came through confirming. Thanks folks - my first time posting here - great experience.